# Vectors and Strings C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> test;
    test.push_back("yasir");
    test.push_back("javed"); 

    for(int i=0; i!=test.end();i++)
    {
        cout << test[i];
    }
}
```

Why is this code giving up an error? I am unable to identify the cause of the error.
Error: No Match for operator !=....

Comment: Please pick up a [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the difference between vector *indexes* and *iterators*.

Comment: In your case simply do: `for(const std::string& s : test) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }`. And once done, please read up:https://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterators.html

Comment: @MABVT , It Works.Thankyou for the reference of the site too

Comment: Also, `std::string` is defined in the header `<string>`, not `<cstring>` or `<string.h>` (which are for C-style strings).

Comment: You are iterating wrongly. Change vector<string>::iterator i = test.begin(). Also since you are iterating, the cout line should be: cout << *i;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to compare `int` with the iterator of vector.

```
for(int i=0; i!=test.end();i++)
{
    cout << test[i];
}
```

Here, the `test.end()` returns the iterator. There is no overloaded `operator!=` which can compare integer (`int i = 0`) with that iterator (`test.end()`).

So your loop should look more like:

```
for (std::vector<string>::iterator i = test.begin(); i != test.end(); i++)
{
    cout << *i;
}
```

You can replace `std::vector<string>::iterator` with `auto`, if using  C++11 or newer.

The next thing, you included `<string.h>` which contains old functions such as: `strlen`, `strcpy`. Similarly, `<cstring>` contains C-style strings.

If you want to you use `operator<<`, so if you want to write:`cout <<` then you have to do: `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the problem is, that you try to compare an integer with an iterator in the "middle" of your for statement. Try this instead, it's more intuitive from my point of view

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        vector<string> test;
        test.push_back("yasir");
        test.push_back("javed"); 

        for(int i=0; i<test.size();++i)
        {
            cout << test[i];
        }
    }
```